# Android: Cannot Resolve Symbol 'content_frame'

Tags: android

So I have created a navigation drawer and it was all working fine. I went away from my pc for a quick break and my computer crashed and as a result it is now throwing that error. Anyone got any ideas I have tried rebuilding the project cleaning etc?

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.content_main_menu) {
        //go to main menu
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_insulin_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new InsulinTrackerFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_bmi_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new BmiFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_reminders_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new RemindersFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_leaderboard_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new LeaderboardFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a "invalidate cache and restart" under file menu.

Your R.java has got corrupted and needs rebuild of indices. After the step i mentioned, do a clean build from under the Build menu

Also a Build -> rebuild project should help after the invalidation.

Comment: Also make sure that there are no errors in your /res folder. A corrupted xml can also lead to this error.

Comment: File-> invalidate cache and restart... My bad for the first try

Comment: Not on the actual ide ;) a bit rusty on the exact menu item name sorry :)

Comment: Glad it helped you :) it's a small thing that has happened to all of us atleast once :'D